# UIImageView disappears randomly?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

In my widget extension, I have only the following code that gets called when the widget appears, nowhere in the code, am I adjusting the frame or hidden properties of _imageView. However, every time this code is executed, the code works fine and does what it is supposed to, but the _imageView disappears. At first I thought that the _imageView was being removed from the view somehow, so then I added a log to log out the frame of the _imageView, to check. The logs come back fine.

I then found out that if I were to scroll through notification center to where the widget is no longer showing, and then scroll back, where I can then see my widget again, the imageView is back, no problem.

Why is the _imageView "disappearing," when this code is being executed?

```
   if (copiedString && ![textArray containsObject:copiedString]) {

            NSLog(@"String was found, and string hasn't been added before.");

            NSLog(@"Image view frame, is it still there? %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_imageView.frame));

            [textArray addObject:copiedString];

            [defaults setObject:textArray forKey:@"array"];
            [defaults synchronize];

        } else {

            NSLog(@"Nothing interesting here, contents of clipboard: string: %@ image: %@", copiedString, copiedImage);

            NSLog(@"Image view frame, is it still there? %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_imageView.frame));

            [defaults setObject:imageArray forKey:@"imagesArray"];
            [defaults synchronize];

        }

        [_tableView reloadData];

        if (imageArray.count != 0 && self.imageFunctionalityEnabled) {

            if (![defaults boolForKey:@"autoAdd"]) {

                if (textArray.count <= 5) {
                    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 199 + textArray.count * 43.5);
                } else if (textArray.count >= 5) {
                    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 199 + 217.5);
                }

            } else {

                if (textArray.count <= 5) {
                    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 155 + textArray.count * 43.5);
                } else if (textArray.count >= 5) {
                    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 155 + 217.5);
                }

            }

        } else {

            if (![defaults boolForKey:@"autoAdd"]) {

                if (textArray.count <= 5) {
                    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 44 + textArray.count * 43.5);
                } else if (textArray.count >= 5) {
                    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 44 + 217.5);
                }

            } else {

                if (textArray.count <= 5) {
                    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0 + textArray.count * 43.5);
                } else if (textArray.count >= 5) {
                    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0 + 217.5);
                }

            }

        }

        [defaults setInteger:[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].changeCount forKey:@"changeCount"];


    }
```

Comment: Where and how is _imageView defined?

Comment: When the image view is not visible, does the height of your today widget change? Or is it always the same size?